# C# calling a webservice result in 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to call a simple web service to get long and lat of an address, which works when I try it manually :

```
https://services.gisgraphy.com/geocoding/?address=paris
```

But with the code, I get 401 unauthorize.. What am I doing wrong ?

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://services.gisgraphy.com/geocoding/?address=paris");
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // It happens here.
```

Comment: Why are you passing the DefaultCredentials? Did you try without doing that? Did you read through their documentation and see what authentication is necessary?

Comment: Same error appears without it, I did it simply because I followed a code on the internet.. I did not read through their documentation.. I will now hope it will help @mason

Comment: What else can it be? ..

Comment: @mason Couldn't find anything there regarding the authentication..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You haven't read the big blue bar on top of [the website belonging to the API you're calling](https://services.gisgraphy.com/static/leaflet/index.html):

> Gisgraphy is open sources and only use open data. This server is for demonstration only. Test it, Play with webservices but then Install Gisgraphy locally or subscribe to premium hosted services

So they're probably detecting that you're calling their API from outside their playground, and are denying you to do so.

So, either install it locally, or subscribe to their hosted services. The latter probably gives you an API key that allows you to make API calls.

Of course you can fake your way around this by imitating that your request comes from a browser, for example with User-agent and Accept headers, but surely they'll try and detect this and block your IP address entirely. Just pay up, or host it locally.

Comment: Should they not use a key? It can easily be accessed if you fake a webbrowser.

Comment: @VDWWD that might work. But it also might work just temporarily, see last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Few things on this question :

- Check if the URL/web-service is directly accessible via
  browser/postman tool.
- Secondly , as one of my fellow friend there    mentioned this
  web-service has some security protocol. May be its not    allowing
  requests from outside (i.e. other than its domain to come    in)

Once you drill down the above two possibility ,you should be in a good shape to move ahead.